# SELECT Top (OuterQuery.Amount) * FROM 

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a problem dealing with the following construct:

```
SELECT *
FROM X
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT TOP (X.IntegerAmount) *
    FROM Y
) AS Z ON X.ID = Z.X_ID
```

Is there a solution for this problem?

Comment: If you don't see the problem than you can't provide the solution...

Comment: As a side note sql doesn't allow the "TOP (ValueFromTable)" construct...

Comment: I did see it some time later. To be honest, I saw it after seeing @gbn's answer and everything became clear at once. You might not always be so lucky to have a person to spot the problem so quickly without your stating it explicitly.

Comment: As a side note, you might want to acquaint yourself with [this article](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't parameterise TOP with the value from another table

You can use a ranking function

```
SELECT *
FROM X
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY SomeVal) as rn, *
    FROM Y
) AS Z ON X.ID = Z.X_ID
WHERE
   Z.rn <= X.IntegerAmount)
```

Or you'd have to make the derived query a UDF with a @topparameter

Note: you need an ORDER BY anyway

There are probably better ways to do what you actually want: this is answer to the what you actually asked which probably isn't the same thing...

Comment: No actually these are the same things

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

I think i understand, try this:

```
DECLARE @i as INT = 10
SET @SQL + 'SELECT * FROM X INNER JOIN 
(     
    SELECT TOP 
    ' +CAST(@i AS NVARCHAR(10))  + ' *     
    FROM Y 
) AS Z     
ON     X.ID = Z.X_ID'
EXEC sp_executesql  @SQL
```